# Calling non abstract methods from an abstract class

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, abstract

I've searched and read my text book for what is probably a basic question but can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following 3 classes. One abstract, one interface and a regular class. 
In the Cat class I want to call the Animal class constructors within a Cat constructor method but get an error. What am i doing wrong?

```
package MyPet;
public interface WalkMe {
        public void walk();
}


package MyPet;
public abstract class Animal{ 
    private int legs;
    private String name;

    public abstract String toString();

    public Animal(int legs_in, String name_in){
            setLegs(legs_in);
            setName(name_in);       
                }
    ...removed the rest of code
}

package MyPet;
public class Cat extends Animal implements WalkMe{

    public void walk() {
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public String toString() { 
    }

    public Cat(){
        Animal(0, "Unnamed"); //THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH I am trying to call the animal Constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat[] cats = new Cat[4];
        cast[0] = new Cat();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answered my questions. I was unaware of the "super" keyword so i was unable to search for this specifically. But this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract constructors aren't meant to be called using their name. In a subclass, to call one, you use `super(args);`.

So you would change:

```
public Cat(){
    Animal(0, "Unnamed");
}
```

to

```
public Cat(){
    super(0, "Unnamed");
}
```

which should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Super class should be refer by the key word `super`, not with Name of it

```
 public Cat(){
        super(0, "Unnamed"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Cat(){
    super(0, "Unnamed");
}
```